# How to build a variable input Voltage Power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer, step-down

The following shows a simple regulated transformer supply

[image: 230 to 5v DC power transformer]

This unit needs 230 Volt Input to produce 5 Volt.

But I'd like to build a power supply that can handle both 120V and 230 Volt. Like this one here [5V Buck convert with variable input voltage](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/191731850965). It accepts AC 85 ~ 265 v.  What do I need to add to make it accept different voltages?

Comment: Do you want to [have to] flip a switch [between 120/230] or do you expect it to happen automagically? In the latter case, you can mostly forget about a linear supply, you'll want a switching supply instead. (A buck converter is one of those.)

Comment: It works on a different principle to the circuit you have so there is no modify this to make that at all.

Comment: yes, I'd like it automagically. So i'll go for switching supply. thanks!

Comment: Easiest - get a 115/230V primary transformer and forget the electronics.

Comment: if you are asking the question, you might not want to be experimenting with mains voltages. Due to safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about as simple a circuit that looks like it might work the way you want: -

[image]

About the only commonality between this and yours is the bridge rectifer if you used 1N4007 devices (rated at 1000 volts). Bare in mind that the circuit above has a lot of detail missing like the turns ratios of the high frequency flyback transformer (nothing at all like the transformer you have of course). There is also an opto coupler to sample the output side so that the TOPSwitch device can regulate the output voltage.

Here's one that uses a Viper 12 chip and this looks more reasonable in terms of all the components needed: -

[image]

You can get more details from [this](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/flyback-converter-%28110-220v-line-power-to-5v%29/) blog